# Directive not rendering inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

The directive test-dir fails to render

```
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="person in data">
        <table>
          <thead>{{person.name}}</thead>
          <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="row in person.entries">
             <test-dir data="row"></test-dir>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
  </ul>

app.directive("testDir", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          data: '='
        },
        template: "<td>{{data}}</td>"
    };
});
```

It does render when used as an attribute. Not sure why it wouldn't work as an element.

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/fraBDzt9kjZlUIuV1fDf?p=preview

Comment: have you added `ng-app` to html?

Comment: Apparently it works if you move the <td></td> out of the directive template http://plnkr.co/edit/VMq2PArcQeRaBcFiDagk?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add `replace: true` to `testDir` directive.

Otherwise you'll have a `<div>` inside a `<tr>` which is why the directive is not rendered when used as element.

However, even with `replace: true` you will encounter a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459):

```
Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: <td>{{data}}</td>
```

Better use the directive as `attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ng-repeat with directive like `<test-dir ng-repeat="row in person.entries" data="row"></test-dir>`

**So your code will be**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
<script>
     var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.directive("testDir", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          data: '='
        },
        template: "<td>{{data}}</td>"
    };
});


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data = [
    {
      name: 'cars',
      entries: [
        {model: 'fiat', speed: 100 },
        {model: 'tesla', speed: 200 },
        ]
    },
    {
      name: 'trucks',
      entries: [
        {model: 'volvo', speed: 50 },
        {model: 'merc', speed: 75 },
        ]
    }
    ];

});
</script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="person in data">
        <table>
          <thead>{{person.name}}</thead>
          <tbody>
           <tr >
             <test-dir ng-repeat="row in person.entries" data="row"></test-dir>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
  </ul>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @OP - Replace `template: "<td>{{data}}</td>"` with `template: "<td>{{data.model}}</td><td>{{data.speed}}</td>"`

Comment: How will this create new rows in the table ?